# Objects clamped to curve shift after moving or extruding the curve

Tags: objects, path

heres an immage to show example  (I updated the image)
https://imgur.com/a/wOY5br9
Problem:
Objects clamped to curve shift after moving or extruding the curve even tho its not supposed to do that.
Like even if the change is many extrudes away, no longer moving (or stretching) the path with the object on it, it still shifts its location drastically. I tried using all paths or curves...same outcome. :C
+ It seems to not follow paths rotation... side question.

Id be very grateful if anyone could help. Thank you!

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Thanks for update, but image is not still placed in the post as Ramos asked for, thanks you care. BTW Clamp is designed to keep bone on curve not follow for more see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/animation/constraints/tracking/clamp_to.html

Comment: Yes I am aware of follow path option but this is actually a bone of a snake, so i need to have best manual control over its location on the curve. and follow path gets pre-animated :/ I guess I can fix the shift manually after every change by moving the whole animation. In the link above it says :to get the bits of rotation you do need some other way. How tho? I could not find

Comment: @Cimo Does this works for you?https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/55613/2214

Comment: Yes, i already have the same result with Damped and stretched bones without the curve... somehow :D So  those bones follow an extra curve for slither effect. just the roll is missing

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an object follow path rotation check "follow curve" in Follow Path Constrain options.
I don't know how to prevent the object's shift when curve's shape changes.