# How do I make a 3 dimensional character out of flat picture?

Tags: animation

I have a cartoon character (a lion) that is part of my business logo that I want to put into Blender and animate it somehow. Is there any way I can take a flat picture (JPEG) and transform it into a 3D image and then animate it in Blender?

Comment: Hi, of course, there is a way, but not "few clicks solution". You need make 3D model manually. Or you can animate them as 2D image. Given the fact how you asked, you are no every experienced about graphics, so you can prepare to few months of learning and gain experiences. Because as I wrote: there is no work for few clicks and explain everythig from modeling, throught materials, animation and rendering to compositing is for a book or series of tutorials.

Comment: If you are starting with blender please look at this page of [resources for blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: Thank you so much, I DO have some knowledge of how graphics work but I was wondering if someone here at the Blender forums has found a way to configure vectors for a single dimension image to be transformed into a multi-dimensional image, I do believe it is possible, just haven't figured it out yet. I work with graphics all the time, so, to me, this would be awesome to figure out. I also have a program called Muvizu for animation which is an awesome program but they do not have the option to submit your own images for characters. I will keep on looking for more tips for Blender.

Comment: https://guochengqian.github.io/project/magic123/

Comment: The question is seven years old, and the two answers are almost as old, so it's time for an update. The answer is now that there is a very easy way to do this. See the new answer I've added below.

Answer (score 106):

You may do it using the ***Transformers add on***. It'll transform every flat textured plane into 3d model.
[image]

Activate it in *User Preferences*. Then go to a *Tool Shelf* and choose a desired transform option.
[image]

## OKAY I'M KIDDING :), NOW SERIOUSLY:

***There's no such way to do it fast***. If you manage to invent a tool that may do such thing automatically you'll be probably a millionaire :). While there's a very simple way to transform 3d model into 2D image (using e.g. shapekeys), reverse process is ***impossible*** (at least right now :)).

As @Shubol3D said there are no shortcuts. You'll have to master a lot of skills to create your lion model. It's very time consuming process, so if you like to save it I suggest you to go to ***Blenderartists.org*** forum and make a paid job offer there. There are a lot of super talented people, who may do it for you.

But if you still want to do it by yourself...

## Here are some ultra basic 3d model production steps:

First of all get familiar with this topic: [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender) It's super useful for the blender beginners.

## MODELING

You should start from setting up the ***reference images*** for modelling:

- [How do I set a background image while I am editing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118/how-do-i-set-a-background-image-while-i-am-editing)
- [How do I scale my reference images correctly within Blender and is there an easier way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32020/how-do-i-scale-my-reference-images-correctly-within-blender-and-is-there-an-easi)
- [Modeling with reference image](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61110/modeling-with-reference-image)

First add a cube. Use *Toggle Quad View* option (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) to split the screen into quarters and set separate ***background images*** for each one. Adjust their positions, so they fit the cube position in *Top*, *Front* and *Right* 3D views.
[image]

To make the modeling workflow faster use a ***Mirror Modifier***:

- [Is their a way to create half of a model and duplicate other side](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18934/is-their-a-way-to-create-half-of-a-model-and-duplicate-other-side)
- [How can I make the mirror modifier work right?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/353/how-can-i-make-the-mirror-modifier-work-right)

Divide the cube into two identical parts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and delete one half of it (<kbd>X</kbd>). Add a *Mirror Modifier* to it. Now you may model just one half of the mesh and the other one'll behave symmetrical.

Enter *Edit Mode* and start ***modeling*** basing on the *background images* you set:

- [What techniques are used to begin creating new models?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26869/what-techniques-are-used-to-begin-creating-new-models)

There are few buttons which are very helpful in modeling: <kbd>G</kbd>- for grabing/translating vertices, edges and faces, <kbd>S</kbd>- for scaling them, <kbd>R</kbd>- for rotating, <kbd>E</kbd> for extruding and <kbd>F</kbd> for filling the holes. You may also subdivde the desired faces using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut.

Start with extruding the cube to create a basic shape that fits the background drawings. Then subdivide it successfuly to add more and more geometry and details.
[image]

Thanks to *quad view* you may control the shape of the mesh in every view at once. Fit it to the background drawings as accurately as you can.
[image]

Finally you may add a **Subsurf Modifier** to make your model smooth. Go to the *Modifiers* header, activate it, set the desired subdivision levels and smooth it even more with ***Smooth*** shading option in *Edit* panel of the *Tool Shelf*.
[image]

I think that in your case this tutorial may be a good start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mlGT6T9bfQ
It shows how to create a 3D animal model based on the 2D images.

## UNWRAPPING AND TEXTURING

To ***unwrap*** your model properly you may need to make ***seams*** for it:

- [How to properly unwrap my mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/how-to-properly-unwrap-my-mesh)
- [How to Place the Right Seams for UV Unwrapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21164/how-to-place-the-right-seams-for-uv-unwrapping)

Select the edges you want to put the seams on and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->*Mark Seam*. Now select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>U</kbd>-->*Unwrap*.
[image]

Now you want to put the ***texture*** on your model. Though there are many methods to do it, I prefer the ***texture painting*** with ***Stencil*** method:

- [How to make textures in Blender without any flat work with a painting program? (3D painting)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34564/how-to-make-textures-in-blender-without-any-flat-work-with-a-painting-program)

Select your model, set up the shading type to *Texture* and go to ***Texture Paint*** mode. Add a new *Paint Slot*-->*Diffuse Color* in a *Tools* bookmark of a *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>). Add a new texture in the *Texture* panel on the left, then go to the *Texture* header on the right, select Brush and open a texture, which will be used as a stencil for painting. Paint the texture and save it.
[image]

Now add a ***material*** to the object and assign a newly created image ***texture/textures*** to it:

- [Add an image to an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/add-a-image-to-an-object) (Blender Internal Render)
- [How are texture maps imported into Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/how-are-texture-maps-imported-into-blender) (Cycles Render)

Go to the *Material* header and add a new material (click *New* button).
[image]

***IN BLENDER INTERNAL:*** Go to *Texture* header to assign a texture to it. Add a new texture, set its type to ***Image or Movie***. In *Influence* panel check the ***Color*** checkbox. Set the *viewport shading* to *Texture* to display it on model.
[image]

***IN CYCLES RENDER:***  Go to *Node Editor*, check the *Use Nodes* checkbox and set up nodes as pictured below.
[image]

Basic tutorial showing how to UV unwrap an animal model and apply a texture to it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4ngVoGIj1Q

## RIGGING AND ANIMATION

Now you have to construct the ***rig*** (skeleton) and parent it with your model:

- [how to rig the body](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62108/how-to-rig-the-body)
- [How can I automatically generate vertex groups for an armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/782/how-can-i-automatically-generate-vertex-groups-for-an-armature)

Add a single bone (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Armature*-->*Single Bone*) and extrude it (<kbd>E</kbd>) in *Edit Mode* creating a skeleton. Limbs can be mirrored from one side to other using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> command.
[image]

When your skeleton is ready you may you may parent your mesh with it. In *Object Mode* select your model, then your armature and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*With Automatic Weights*. It'll automatically create specific vertex groups for the specific bones.
[image]

Finally you can ***animate*** your bones:

- [How to make an animation / armature remember poses?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7171/how-to-make-an-animation-armature-remember-poses)

Select a bone in ***Pose Mode***, translate it using <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> and press <kbd>I</kbd> to *keyframe* it. Go to the next frame on the *Timeline*, translate it again and keyframe again. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to play the animation. Adjust your keyframes spacing in *Dope Sheet Editor*. Control every aspect of your animation using curves in *Graph Editor*.
[image]

Very, very basic tutorial showing how to make the skeleton for your animal and how to animate it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kr6-_NT_olo

Comment: that first gif is awesome.

Comment: Will the addon also make auto-rigging and export to youtube with a single mouse click?

Comment: Pack your things boys, this site can now officially be closed. Possibly one of the best answers of BSE **ever**. This basically answers every question about Blender ever made in the past, or that may still rise in the foreseeable future.

Comment: dat gif tho. could you please explain how you did it? is it even yours? lol so amazing.

Comment: @cegaton I've heard the rumors, that it'll have this kind of functionallity until the Blender 3.0 release ;).

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos LOL.

Comment: @ARadish I've just scaled (S-->0) Suzanne, then did some tweaks to create a rectangular plane, keyframed the shape key and textured it (Project from View). Then animated the transition between textured diffuse and color diffuse shaders.

Comment: @PGmath It's quite hard task to explain everything, as every production aspect ***requires*** a tutorial, not a simple answer. I'll try though :).

Comment: So, there could be a transformer's plug in! Just add some topographic-map-like relief data (contour lines) embedded in a rectangular plane mesh, then *reverse* Paul's manual technique, but programmatically scaling (S -->x), where x is the contour data (e.g. "height") at a vertex, then loop through all the vertices. ... or am I hallucinating after staring at that GIF too long?

Comment: @PaulGonet  Way more detail than I had in mind :P thx!

Comment: @PGmath Thanks! This is the most hard-earned upvote I've ever got :D.

Comment: The transformer's plugin is actually technically possible, but there will be some problems such as hidden objects and objects filled in the wrong spot, such as the tail being placed between the 2 pairs of legs and the tail itself (which would look really wrong...)

Comment: @Bradman175 - indeed ... could be useful if the objs are simple ... add the hidden details later. @ Paul Gonet ... thanks for the effort. Answers such as yours are why I'm here!  (And meta.blender has several discussions about the pros and cons of "tutorials" ... SE in general frowns on them, wanting simple, black-and-white answers. Clearly that's impossible for many things Blender, requiring "workflow" answers and details like yours... at some unclear boundary, workflow becomes tutorial. But I sure don't care about that ... so here's to more sophisticated workflow !

Comment: @PaulGonet Why are your answers so good?! You're crushing me inside :D P.S. I totally second Duarte's comment.

Comment: @Shady Puck Thnx! I wish I had the blender knowledge you have when I was your age :).

Comment: This is as good of an answer as anyone is going to give you without having it done for you, mark it as an answer to give the user credit, for not only time and effort for the job, but also because he did so in a way that it is a virtual walkthrough.

Comment: Awesome answer! great gif, too.

Comment: @Paul Gonet Hey, I loved the cat and the monkey. So cool! 

Comment: @PaulGonet: I love how you created the fake "Transformers Add-on" window! You thought of _everything_!!

Answer (score 3):

Use Photoscan,and if it didn't turn out like you wanted then you can use the shapes to make it,but I reccomend using MakeHuman or the Manuel Bastioni Laboratory. I'm making a FNaF fan game with human characters,and when I finally found out about this,I used the sliders to make the character exactly like I wanted to. This is your answer. But if it's a lion you're talking about,I highly recommend that you use reference images to sculpt the anatomy of the lion without mane first,then you model it using the sculpture as a base,then use the Subdivision.

The Subdivision Surface modifier will increase the polygon number,I also recommend you to use image textures from the internet to trace the shape and for symmetry,use a mirror modifier for one side,then when you apply it,swap the weights with their opposites. Then you can detach a limb,one by one and parent it to the armature set with Automatic Weights. Then add mane using hair particles and go to the Blender Guru's site to learn how to make realistic fur.

Comment: Why is everybody down-voting me?

Answer (score 0):

The question is seven years old, and the two answers are almost as old, so it's time for an update. The answer is now:

**Yes, there is a way. A very easy way.**

I don't know if this is the only way, but I found a very easy way in a [YouTube video by Nik Kottmann](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k043OByAG-4):

- Go to the free online tool, [Monster Mash](https://www.MonsterMash.zone).
- Import the picture.
- Draw lines around the segments of the object, such as the body, legs, and ears of an animal.
- Click "Inflate" to magically turn the picture into a 3D object.
- Click "Animate" (not to animate the object, but just to turn on the option for the next step).
- Export the object as a glTF (`.glb`) file.
- Import the glTF file into Blender.
- To see the surface textures from the original picture, change `Viewport Shading` to "Material Preview".
- Switch to Edit Mode to reveal the vertices of the object and modify the object as desired.

The video runs through all the steps for doing the above. Nik takes a picture of a rhinoceros and turns it into a 3D object in Blender in a few minutes. I ran through his steps with a picture I generated in [Leonardo](https://www.Leonardo.AI) and got the same result.

Pretty amazingly easy!

Comment: Thank you for writing the up-to-date answer! It will probably get very old very soon, as better algorithms exist already: https://guochengqian.github.io/project/magic123/ and in the case of Monster Mash, where no fancy stuff is being done to the texture (just a projection from view), anyone with moderate experience in modelling will be able to produce better results within a short span of time (as Paul Gonet's answer shows). Still, this technique could save some minimum amount of time for a basis shape for modelling (paired with quad remesher for good topology)...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - Re Magic123: That does look way better, but it appears to be only available for linux. Do you know anything about when it might be available for Windows or online?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady - Re "anyone with moderate experience in modelling": I'm new to Blender and to animation, but experienced in computers, so not afraid of learning new tools. I was impressed by the extraordinary detail of Paul Gonet's answer, but it seemed it would take a long time to learn what he was teaching. When you say "better results within a short span of time," would you think that I should be able to follow his instructions and get up to speed in the techniques if I give it a solid focus for a day or two, or should I expect a longer learning curve than that?

Comment: I've been using Blender for 5 years and there's still a lot new things I could learn, so I'm not going to lie a single intensive learning session is all you need; however the blenderguru's donut tutorial teaches a lot and can be finished in a day or two. Then just start working on your project and google a problem whenever you have one - also once you get some familiarity with the basics, go through this video to find out about which features you missed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jHUY3qoBu8 ; as for Magic123, I didn't try it, but you can use WSL on Windows.