# clay models stop animation movie with blender ( import clay models inside blender)

Tags: modeling, animation, add-on, import

i have lots of clay models, and want to make a short stop motion animation movie. For animation i choose blender because in traditional stop motion it take lot of time to move the characters then take a shot. My question: is there is any way to import my clay models inside blender ( using video  or different profiles pics of models) ?

Actually i don't want my movies characters loses their "**Physical feel or texture"** i.e appear like clay models in a movie not animated ones. Here is example, for what i mean

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, could you clarify? What do you mean clay models, did you actually physically sculpt clay figures by hand? What do you mean import, did you somehow digitize them or 3D scan the sculptures?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a 3 dimensional character out of flat picture?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture)

Comment: As Duarte said, you need to clarify if you created these clay models in a 3D program, or in real life? To digitalize a real object can be pretty expensive, in most cases (including these) it would be easier and cheaper to just recreate the object digitally. Clay objects can be created using sculpt brushes and material modifications.