# Scale and change certain measurements of 3D image that was imported as .svg file

Tags: modeling, measurement

I have converted a 2D image of an animal into a 3D image in Blender (as an .svg file). I was wondering if I can give the image proper measurements based on a dataset I have (I've attached an image showing the measurements that I have). I essentially want to create a realistic 3D image and then manipulate that image based on the measurements of different individuals. Also if there was a better way to upload and convert that image feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking, could you elaborate. What do you mean "3D Image"? Do you want to manipulate the shape such that the dimensions of each measured part correspond to a certain value, or do you just want to show dimension lines with measurements? Are you trying to customize this for a lot of individuals or just display the different dimensions for each one?

Comment: I've commented below with a better explanation of what I'm trying to get at. I apologize for how confusing the question is, I have never worked with a rendering program in any capacity before so I am very new to this. I want to manipulate the shape such that the dimensions of each measured part correspond to certain values I have. I am customizing this for various individuals to get Surface Area and Volume values via the 3D printing tool. The 3D image would just be a 3D model of a whale. I assumed the easiest way to do this was to import a picture and then convert it to 3D.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a 3 dimensional character out of flat picture?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture)

Answer (score 1):

Frustrated at the way you ask your question ... I created a question back to you.

You will need to describe your application. As in how you intend to use this. I am starting to think that you are a marine bio-scientist who wants to keep a record of all the whales you come across visually? So you need to manipulate the image according to the sizes of the fish? Will the eventual image be just a flat image? Or will your eventual result you need be like Exhibit B. Which is a 3d model of the actual whale? In your previous posting you said you may want to know the surface area of the creature? All very confusing.

**First and foremost please let us know your real intended application.**

Secondly, Look at the image below. And tell us.

[image]

A. You want to import an image accurately into blender?
B. You want to create a 3d model of the whale?
C. You want to do both?
D. We don't understand and misinterpreted your question?

Some Ligo reference, a 3d artist may misunderstand what you really need to do ...
**Realistic 3d image** - A flat 2D image orthographic or perspective rendered/output from a 3d software.
**2D image into a 3D image** - Essentially placing a 2D image on a 3D polygonal plane. Like Exhibit A. 
**Image Proper Measurement** - Image Aspect ratio, so that the image doesn't look out of portion or stretched.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and working with me, as previously stated I have never worked with rendering programs in any capacity so I don't know the lingo/the information necessary to answer my questions.

My goal is to collect data on the Surface Area and Volume of the whales (based on the 3d model as you have it in B).

I want to do both A and B, importing an image accurately to blender and then creating a 3d model of the whale as you have done above. 

Once I have rendered image B above I want to manipulate it based on certain measurements as shown in the image I posted as B.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly if you need accurate measurements like surface area, then what you want is sort of a procedural full 3D base model of whale that you can later manipulate and adjust to certain specific dimensions, not a "2D image". And unless you specifically want to ouput the 2D images along the 3D model, then "step A" is unnecessary, except as reference solely for the initial modelling phase of the base model of the whale.

Comment: What you want to do seems totally achievable and relatively easy to do, but the part to make the model easily adjustable may not be so trivial for beginners. Not sure exactly how one could achieve that, perhaps using hooks, or rigging the model, but that is kind of out of my knowledge. Maybe start by looking at [tutorials about modelling from reference images in Blender](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=blender+modelling+reference+image) may help

Comment: To honestly be really accurate in the modeling of said whale. You may need more than just the top view of the creature. If your data needs extreme and accuracy you would also need the image of the creature's side view. There is a tool within blender where it goes in and draw out the surface area of the object. It's called "3d printing" Under tool panel in the 3d view. I used it often to calculate cost of certain material for civil construction purposes based on the rough surface area I need to cover on a building.

Comment: Hawkenfox- I could very easily get an image of a whale with all three sides. I've already figured out how to get SA and V measurements using the 3D printing tool. What I'm stuck on is actually creating the 3d model from an image as you've done above. I've found some tutorials online that haven't been as helpful as I would have liked. Could you lead me through the steps you took to do this or direct me to a better tutorial.

Comment: Duarte- thanks for your response! I'll check those out!

Comment: The method I used for creating the model is call "box modeling". It starts out as a single plane. And would then progress to form a general outline of the object. And later on in the modeling process, I would add a subdivision modifier that would interpolate the surface and give it that curved and refined look. The box modeling technique I used have been perfected with years of practice and refined shortcuts command which I have painstakingly over the year design them to speed up my workflow. For the whale I created here took me about 10mins. Would have taken a day for me in the pass.

Comment: I have found a useful tutorial on modeling that uses box modeling. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc learn from it, will take awhile. Go through the whole tutorial , I think there are 10 tutorials in the whole set. Try to remember shortcut keys to speed up the workflow. Also remember to use the mirror modifier most objects in the real world have symmetry .