# How to model parts of the face of this character?

Tags: modeling, workflow, topology

I'm trying to model this character of mine for animation and rigging:
[image: Techii]
But every time I try to go about modeling her I always end up getting stuck on either her eyes, nose, or mouth. Those seem the most tricky parts for me.

I've tried spline modeling, sculpting, box modeling, point to point modeling, and even plane modeling. All with different results, but I end up getting stuck when I come across those troublesome areas no matter what.

**Edit 1:** I've also searched for reference images of rabbits, their topology, anatomy, and looked upon other works from other 3d artists to get an idea of what to do. I still end up stuck.

**Edit 2:** I changed the question into something a little less broad but will change it more if necessary, just let me know. Still new to how posting questions works on this site.

Here are some screen shots of my progress.
[image: TechiiBlenderScreenshot1]
[image: TechiiBlenderScreenshot2]

**Edit 3:** Currently trying to sculpt the head again and will do the rest soon. Someone suggested I do a sculpt first, then retopologize everything and work from there. Which sounds easy enough, but still hard to achieve the shape and style to the reference. Though I know I will get it eventually.
Here are some screenshots:
[image: TechiiSculpt_Front_Side]

[image: TechiiSculpt_Front]

[image: TechiiSculpt_3/4]

Comment: Your link to the image seems to be broken... Check the permission on your google drive sharing settings.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Unfortunately as it stands this question is too broad to be answerable here without modelling the whole character. Could you maybe show us how far you got modeling the head and perhaps show screenshots of what specific issues you were stuck with? It might be easier to help you solve those

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad. Try to focus the question into a single specific issue. Break different questions into different posts. You can ask many questions, but it is easier to organize things if you deal with one issue at the time in different posts. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] section. Particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me out here. I will keep my posts more organized in the future :)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&biw=1920&bih=1014&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=COBsWvnhJIiu0gLn1p6wCQ&q=face+edge+flow&oq=face+edge+flow&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i5i30k1.5080.6069.0.6377.8.6.0.0.0.0.152.535.4j2.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.2.183...0i30k1.0.9qP-zlhyJSw

Comment: I am by no means an expert in organic modelling or character edgeflow but I'd say from what I've seen around it looks like your base mesh is too complex as too many polygons. Try simplifying it a little. See http://topologyguides.com

Comment: While character modeling is topic by itself and main rules should be picked from general guides and tutorials, you can take topology example of similar character made before https://www.furaffinity.net/view/19319760/

Comment: @MrZak As it turns out, I was following that example beforehand :D, but wasn't sure how to reference the topology and tweak it a little to fit my character, especially at the angle their model is in.

Comment: CGCookie has [some videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLeHdyJXgqu09C1UNlQFiSp6-yuyXLED-I) showing good edge loops. Your edge loops need to follow the shape of your character, that includes the shape when it is animated into an extreme pose. You have good loops around the eyes, maybe getting too dense. The cheeks and under the chin you are too square, you need to follow the shape more.