# Modeling a Mambele

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves

I am attempting to model a mambelle, a sickle sword, and I am using curves to try and model. I am running into issues where I get the only partial outline, or I get the outline but the model is solid.  What would be the best way to approach this?[image: mambelle]

I have attached the picture of the weapon. My experience level is noob, I understand the controls and I know some modeling techniques while making potholes for a video game I want to develop, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you have been able to produce so far?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you want and what you are seeing. As Sazerac says, a screenshot would help. Some things to try would be alt-C to open/close the curve/loop and playing with the options in the Object Data (curve) panel which gives you things like 3D/2D and Fill Mode.

Comment: why are you using curves? It would be easier with vertices, just follow the blade profile, and make a different mesh for the handle

Comment: Thank you all for the input, I did start all over and used vertices, but I will try again using curves just to better understand how they work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How do I make an object out of a flat picture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture)

Answer (score 3):

Start out by getting a reference image into blender. Using 2.8, I did Add > Image > Reference, and chose the image I wanted to use. Then I positioned a cube along the blade like below:
[image: start]

(I rotated the image so the handle matched up with the y axis just for convenience, but that isn't really necessary). Also make sure your viewport is looking directly down from above (you can use View > Align View >Align View to Active > Top) when adding the reference image.

In edit mode, I then extruded the top and bottom of the cube following the image, so that it matched up from the top (make sure you are in top view and have orthographic view on for this part, as it makes it easier).

[image: 2]

By repeatedly extruding and scaling the ends of the cube, I got it to match up to the handle.

I then repeat the same process for the blade, except make the cube thinner on the Z axis first.

[image: 3]

After it looks how you want it on the top, switch out of top view so you can make sure it looks how you want it on the z-axis, I needed to scale mine down a lot.

Then I just add in some materials, one of them being metallic for the blade, the other brown for wood, and I was done. I also added in a Subdivision Surface modifier so it looked a bit smoother.

Result:
[image: final]

I hope this helps, let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: thank you so much! It does help, and i hope you will see just how this model plays into what we're planning!