# Texture is only showing in a small place

Tags: texture-painting

My texture only shows up in a small place of my composition.[image]
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, you need to unwrap correctly, please show your UV Editor, or share your file (with the image packed inside): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You should definitely check some Unwrap or UV mapping technique. Here is one found randomly https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture/63256#63256