# Is it possible to render a 3D model and image from a 2D picture

Tags: 3d-view, 2d

I have begun to create custom car and motorcycle works so that I build them in real life.

Is there anyone that has had any luck entering 3D models from an uploaded 2D image, and if so, how was it done?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture

Comment: for the moment there's not magic way to convert 3D to 2D as explained in the link given by Susu, but maybe be more specific, what kind of object, etc... you can quickly model something that looks like your object and project a texture on it for example

Comment: You never know.. a couple of papers down the line.. AI might be able to make a [good guess](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BjwhMDhbqAs) :D

Comment: I’m trying to take 2D pictures of my motorcycle and then somehow form them into a workable 3D model that I can then toy and play around with in order to see how it is now and compare side by side a newer customized model